# GCM (Google-cloud-messaging) load received push messages

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I found recently, that my app doesn't load PUSH notification send with GCM.
When I load app and is Active. It is working. App receive message. When is in background, it is working too.
But when app is Not running and I receive push message in Notifications, I open app. But app don't load sended push messages.

What can be reason of this behavior?

Comment: Do provide your payload and some code snippets.

Comment: The way you described it, you are opening the app first and expecting it to "load" (to your phrase) the notification. Is that what you are doing? If so there is no such thing, you have to tap on the notification in order for the app to load and get the payload.